# How to convert Class object into json string

Tags: python, json, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this class in python:

```
class Defendant(db.Model, DictSerializable):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name_Full = db.Column(db.Text, index=True)
```

I'm using SqlAlchemy to query the database to get results back.  It's working fine, I can push them out to the screen without issues iterating through one by one.

Now I need to get them into a json array so I can do some cool grid stuff.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
Defendants = models.Defendant.query.limit(50).all()
defendantList = ""
for d in Defendants:
    defendantList += "{Name_Full : " + d.Name_Full + "}"
```

I've tried various things like jsonify(Defendants), etc, but I'm missing something.  I get errors with dict or serializeable or iterable.

This seems like a pretty simple thing to do, and I hope I'm just missing something.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"{Name_Full : " + d.Name_Full + "}"` is not valid JSON. Don't even try to build the string yourself; give `jsonify()` simple Python objects, like a list of dictionaries: `[{'Name_Full': d.Name_Full} for d in Defendants]`.

Comment: the code you provided gives this error:  dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: You cannot pass that list directly to `jsonify()`, because that acts just like `dict()` does. You'll have to give it a key first, like `jsonify(results=[...])`.

Comment: ok, considering json.dumps works similarly, I've switched to that.  Here's the result I'm getting though:
[{&#34;Name_Full&#34;: &#34;Smith, John&#34;}, ...]

how do I prevent it from encoding the ' marks?

Comment: You are putting this into a HTML template? Then use the `listobject|json|safe` Jinja2 expression instead.